# Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to differentiate a function of two variables defined by an integral

Tags: calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I'm having problems differentiating the following integral in $t$ $$\psi(x,t)=\int^{t}_{0}f(x + b(s-t),s)ds$$ with $b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x,t) \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you try starting with the definition of the derivative? What went wrong?

Comment: Use [Leibnitz's Rule for differentiating under the integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: As a general rule when dealing with differentiating with respect to a variable $t$ used in multiple roles, it is useful to introduce new variables for each of the individual roles, then consider those variables to be functions of $t$ and apply the multivariable chain rule. In this case: $$\Psi(x, u, v) = \int_0^u f(x + b(s - v), s)\,dx\\\frac{d}{dt}\psi(x,t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial u}\Psi(x,u,v)\frac{du}{dt} + \frac{\partial}{\partial v}\Psi(x,u,v)\frac{dv}{dt}$$ Setting $u = v = t$ tells you how to handle the multiple roles.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it using the definition, "a trick" and some analysis exercises at penultimate and last lines.

First, call $f(x-b(s+t),s) = \pi(s,t)$.

Then,
\begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[ \int_{0}^{t}\pi(s,t)ds \right] &=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{t+h}\pi(s,t+h)ds - \int_{0}^{t}\pi(s,t)ds }{h}\\
  &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{t+h}\pi(s,t+h)ds}{h} - \frac{\int_{0}^{t}\pi(s,t)ds}{h}\\
  &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{t+h}\pi(s,t+h)ds}{h} - \frac{\int_{0}^{t+h}\pi(s,t)ds}{h} + \frac{\int_{0}^{t+h}\pi(s,t)ds}{h} - \frac{\int_{0}^{t}\pi(s,t)ds}{h}\\
  &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{t+h}\pi(s,t+h) - \pi(s,t) ds}{h} + \frac{\int_{0}^{t+h}\pi(s,t)ds}{h} + \frac{\int_{t}^{0}\pi(s,t)ds}{h}\\
  &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{t+h}\pi(s,t+h) - \pi(s,t) ds}{h} + \frac{\int_{t}^{t+h}\pi(s,t)ds}{h}\\
  &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{t}\pi(s,t+h) - \pi(s,t) ds}{h} + \frac{\int_{t}^{t+h}\pi(s,t+h) - \pi(s,t) ds}{h} + \frac{\int_{t}^{t+h}\pi(s,t)ds}{h}\\
  &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{t}\pi(s,t+h) - \pi(s,t) ds}{h} + \frac{\int_{t}^{t+h}\pi(s,t+h)ds}{h} - \frac{\int_{t}^{t+h}\pi(s,t) ds}{h} + \frac{\int_{t}^{t+h}\pi(s,t)ds}{h}\\
  &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{t}\pi(s,t+h) - \pi(s,t) ds}{h} + \frac{\int_{t}^{t+h}\pi(s,t+h)ds}{h}\\
  &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{t}\pi(s,t+h) - \pi(s,t) ds}{h} + \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{t}^{t+h}\pi(s,t+h)ds}{h}\\
  & = \int_{0}^{t}\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\pi(s,t+h) - \pi(s,t) ds}{h} + \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \cdot \int_{t}^{t+h}\pi(s,t+h)ds\\
  &= \int_{0}^{t}\frac{\partial\pi(s,t)}{\partial x}ds + \pi(t,t)
 \end{align*}

Thanks for the comments!